# How to transfer code from a route to a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

I have routes

```
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Navbar />
                <div className="container pt-4">
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/" exact component={Home}></Route>
                        <Route path="/files" component={Files}></Route>
                        <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn}></Route>
                        <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp}></Route>
                        <Route path="/:url_code" component={File}></Route>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
```

How can I pass `:url_code` an `File` page.

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

import { Item } from './../components/Item.component';

export const File = () => {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <h3>test</h3>
            <hr />
            <Item />
        </Fragment>
    );
};
```

Comment: You should try and `console.log` argument props in your File component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to give your component access to react-router's `match` object. You can do this with a higher-order component called `withRouter`. This gives you access to `location`, `history`, and `match` as props passed to your component. From there you can extract your `url_code` fragment via `match.params`.

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

import { Item } from './../components/Item.component';
const File = ({ match }) => {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <h3>{match.params.url_code}</h3>
            <hr />
            <Item />
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export withRouter(File)
```